# I put vinegar on my monitor

Tags: display, desktop-computer, white-screen

I used vinegar in attempt to get some gunk off a monitor (not owned by me). Now the screen is completely white, with a few vertical lines and two spots.

I'm shoving it in the sun for a morning in Arizona heat (there is no better solution to a wet electronic than drying it).

What to do if that doesn't solve the problem?

The structure of the screen is fine. I applied the vinegar only to the screen.

It's all dry now. It's still dark right now. Just after I wiped it with a paper towel covered in vinegar and plugged it in, the entire image was white minus a couple of purple-ish lines.

It's just a white screen, so I don't see how posting a picture of it would help.

Comment: Why would you shove it in the Arizona sun as a solution?  If that doesn't work, will you fix it by beating it with a hammer?  When you say you "used" vinegar, what was the exact procedure?  We'll need to see a picture to understand the situation.

Comment: The surface isn't still wet, so there is nothing to dry.  Did you just wipe it with a rag with some vinegar or immerse the whole thing in vinegar?  We don't know what you mean by "white".  Does it have a white surface film, an etched screen surface, or the surface is normal and it is just displaying an entirely white image?  Could you have affected the internal electronics, or pressed hard on the screen, or damaged the polarizing layer?  There are many possibilities that can only be understood by seeing a picture.

Comment: it sounds like vinegar got into the electronics.  More than likely the monitor is destroyed.

Comment: Organic acids in aqueous solution are *highly* conductive. You can try to clean off the electronics (primarily the drivers on the flat flex cables) with deionized or distilled water, but be prepared to shell out for a whole new monitor.

Comment: Most modern screens (yes pedants, I know about the exception) basically have a backlight, and a LCD layer in front that blocks out light of various colours from it. Sounds like the bits that control blocking out light, and creating an image... might be damaged. Unless you're a skilled electronics repairer, diagnosing and fixing the problem's going to be really hard, and involve opening the monitor.

Comment: Interestingly, howtoforge recommends 50/50 white vinegar/water for cleaning https://www.howtogeek.com/170080/the-how-to-geek-guide-to-cleaning-your-lcd-monitor-screen/ Dell suggests dedicated LCD cleaning solution (a isopropyl alcohol solution) and Samsung water...

Comment: Well if I'm going to have to replace it, I'm going to tweak with it a bit to see if it'll help.

Comment: You have checked the connectors (at *both* ends of the cable) are still securely seated, haven't you...

Comment: You don't spray any solution onto a monitor directly, instead spray a towel then use that to clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chemicals can quickly change plastics / screen and I'm sure manufacturers didn't test their products how - If there is a way at all - to restore them after contact with random chemicals.

As vinegar contacted the screen only, the screen must be the component failing.

Most likely it's not possible to restore it.  (Other way than replacing the screen).

### Update to answer comments:

> Or there was an unrelated failure at the same time

Yes, that could happened too.

> Some had to of slipped down the screen into it.

If you've applied only a small amount of vinegar and your monitor was positioned in a normal direction (vertical screen) then it's very unlikely vinegar could find its way to the electronics.

> The white background with spots seems to me more likely to indicate physical damage that occurred during the cleaning, not necessary liquid damage

That can be a possible reason too, anyway we would need to know more, see the monitor to say anything more.

Comment: Or there was an unrelated failure at the same time.

Comment: Some had to of slipped down tge screen into it.

Comment: The white background with spots seems to me more likely to indicate physical damage that occurred during the cleaning, not necessary liquid damage.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of your procedure and the symptoms, I'm guessing the vinegar didn't cause the problem.

Instead, your methods physically broke the screen. I'd need a picture to confirm this, but the description of a white screen with a few spots/dots sounds like there are cracks in the screen caused by the misapplication of pressure to the screen.

A light vinegar/water solution is just fine for screens, but you always apply this to a towel/rag to dampen it only (you don't want drips dripping down into the electronics).

One other thing: putting LCDs into direct sunlight, unless they are designed for this, is a bad idea too. Electronics are dried most safely with air, not heat or radiation (sunlight).